# How do I change the font colour in Front facing Joomla Forms

Tags: profile, joomla, forms

I am having an issue with the front facing forms in Joomla all the labels are white on a white background. How can I change the label font colour on all forms/profiles to black?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add styling in your theme css file to over-ride the default style.

Answer (score 0):

The most commen cause of this problem with Joomla is that Civi adds styling specific to the `div.crm-container label` selector, and Bootstrap-based themes, and Joomla's Admin theme also styles `label`. Which part of the CSS you need to override depends on your front-end theme, but as Pradeep says, editing this is how to fix your problem.

If you are new to debugging CSS, use the Inspector panel in your browser..

[image: screengrab of browser popup menu]

and you can see all the different selectors impacting the `label`.

[image]

Generally selectors in Inspector that are higher-up override those further down in the 'cascade'. 'cascade' in Cascading Style Sheets refers to the order in which style information loads. So it sounds like CiviCRM's styles are loading higher in the cascade than your template's. By hovering over the different CSS filenames on the right, you can find which styling is added by your template, and what you'll specifially need to overwrite:

[image]